# how to display a text on right using magento

Tags: magento

I have written a code that displays a text hello world on right of the magento homepage, but however when I browse to other links like My Account, My WishList etc., it disappears. My question is how will I be able to display Hello World in every pages using reference name="right"?

```
<default>
 <reference name="right">
  <block type="core/template" name="catalog.helloworld" template="catalog/helloworld.phtml" />
 </reference>
</default>
```

It works when I write reference name = "content".

Comment: Because it displays the content what you write as a content.

Comment: Can u please suggest, how to display the text on right then?

Comment: If you use `<reference name="right">`, then use this in your `catalog/helloworld.phtml` file: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>`. Please let me know if this works!!

Comment: You mean like this:<?php
 echo "Hello World";
?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?> This is my helloworld.phtml page   Its not working

Comment: First write this: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>` and then write `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>`

Comment: Done. But yet not working

Comment: What is your template in `setTemplate` method?

Comment: My template name is layout

Comment: Then include that line in `layout`. You need include that where you set the template in `setTemplate` method and print echo statement in your `helloworld` file

Comment: Is it working??

Comment: I have not written any setTemplate method anywhere. I just made a theme layout. I am new in magento.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134343/discussion-between-birju-and-hiren-gohel).

Answer (score 1):

The text is displayed where the block "right" is present, you can search your project for `<remove name="right"/>` and find where right block has been removed for the pages (my wishlist, myaccount, etc..)

Now you can enable this block by removing these tags, or (recommended) you can create your own block and add it to layout/page.xml